# bootstrap 5 navbar in 2 rows

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to create this navbar design, but I also want to maintain the responsiveness, hamburger menu but only for the upper part (home, contact us, etc links)

[image: Navbar]

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.orange {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-black">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <div class="red">a</div>
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler ms-auto" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-menu">
                    <div class="yellow"></div>
                </span>
            </button>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active text-white active-page fs-2" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link text-white fs-2" href="#">Rooms</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link text-white fs-2" href="#">Team</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link text-white fs-2" href="#">Info</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link text-white fs-2" href="#">Contact us</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="d-none d-lg-block bg-white p-3">
        <!-- Have to make like this, if i put everything in a single div it brakes -->
        <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
          <div class="col-3 d-flex align-items-center">
            <span class="font-SansSerifBldFLFCond text-blue">CALL US NOW</span>
            <div class="orange">s</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-3 d-flex align-items-center">
            <p class="text-blue">From</p>
            <div id="today-date ">
              <h4 class="fs-6 text-blue">SUNDAY</h4>
              <p class="fs-3">15 May</p>
            </div>
            <div class="orange">s</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-3 d-flex align-items-center">
            <p class="text-blue">To</p>
            <div id="tomorrow-date">
              <h4 class="fs-6 text-blue">MONDAY</h4>
              <p class="fs-3">16 May</p>
            </div>
            <div class="orange">s</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-3 d-flex align-items-center">
            <p class="text-blue font-SansSerifBldFLFCond">INFO</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

First main problem is I want to center the links (home, about info)

Second, I want to remove all the padding and margin so the icon (red div) have the same height of the Navbar.

And final thing The height of the 2 columns (links and calendar, phone ecc) should be 50% of the logo each, so combined they have the same height of the logo

Comment: To center the links, you can replace the me-auto class for mx-auto.

Comment: I think I can help here, but if you could please make your working example a little clearer that would help me. What you will probably need to do is make to seperate navbars one that is responsive and one that is not.

Comment: I want to have the responsive part (defult hamburger menu and it's working). But I also want to have the navbar with the same deign in the image, the red dive is the logo, orange div are the calendar icons, and the yellow is the hamburger icon. the navbar should have 2 separate rows (as you cam seen in the pic), the first row are the links (they should be sapaced around ) . The seonc row comprend 4 colums the contet of the colums must be centered but the colum it self must be spaced between.